# Easy way to prove that $c(\lambda,q,t)*P_\lambda(x;q,t)$ (integral form macdonald polynomial) has polynomial coefficients?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I looked at the branching formula of MacDonald polynomial $P_\lambda$ but
that formula does not imply that  $c(\lambda,q,t)*P_\lambda(x;q,t)$ has polynomial coefficients.

Besides using a well-known combinatorial formula (e.g filling formula), is there an elementary way to see that?

Comment: You're asking about polynomial coefficients in the monomial basis, right?

Comment: yes right, monomial basis coefficients.